# Meteor: Fetching Data From Account-Twitter Mongo Collection

Tags: mongodb, twitter, meteor, user-accounts

I'm trying to display some data from the accounts-twitter package. I need the user's profile pic, username, and name, all from Twitter. I've checked using `meteor mongo` to see that this data is in there. `Profile.html` is where I store my templates for this:

```
<template name="profile">
    <div class="col s4">
    <div class="z-depth-2">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <img class="circle-profile center-align" src="{{services.twitter.profile_image_url}}" style="border-radius: 50%" width="50px" height="50px"/>
          <br>
          <span class="card-title">{{profile.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="http://twitter.com/{{services.twitter.screenName}}">View Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="display">
  {{#each users}}
    {{> profile}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

I also have profile.js that fetches the data from the collection using a helper:

```
Template.display.helpers({
  users: function() {
    return Mongo.users.find();
  }
});
```

When I look at my main area, the profiles I have in the collection aren't showing. Please advise. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user)

The profile is published by default and only updatable by the current user. The services, where the Twitter information is stored is not because that would be a security issue since it contains the authentication tokens. What would probably work best is in the `onCreateUser()` method copy those values to the profile so they are published.

You could also publish only those fields you need from the services but I personally like to keep that separate since it contains sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks! I just published only the profile image, username, and name fields that I needed from Twitter.